# How to put icons into the toolbar in a core-scaffold in the Polymer Designer Tool

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to put multiple icons in the top-right bar of a core-scaffold in the Polymer Designer Tool. But when I drag a button to there it snaps back to the main white area.
How do I put buttons in that location (see image, right top of the bar)

Thanks!
http://imgur.com/zq9SEuG

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the design tool, but in your own project do the following.

```
<core-scaffold>
<!--  everything else that the core-scaffold uses -->
<div tool>
    <!-- Put your buttons here -->
</div>
<!-- anything you want in the body -->
</core-scaffold>
```

That should do what you're looking for.